# STS Visualisation of Spring Integration Java DSL flow

Tags: java, spring-integration, spring-tool-suite

Does anybody know if there is currently a way, in STS/Eclipse, to visualise an `IntegrationFlow` defined as a bean using **Spring Integration Java DSL**, as is possible via the 'integration-graph' tab available when editing SI-XML-defined flows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it isn't possible, because Java DSL doesn't generate XML at all. But that STS graph is fully based on the XML.

We are working for the `Flo for SI DSL` project to do something similar for Java DSL, but it is private yet.